# Nested menu with Template 10

Tags: win-universal-app, template10

I want to use the Hamburger menu from Template 10 and add dynamic sections,

for example

--Mail section (header)

------Inbox

------Sent Items

--Calendar (header)

-----etc..

list of headers, for each item, there is a list of clickable items.

Is there a way to bind the primary buttons and add a template for the items?
something like that
[image]

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: I did it manually, I have added a split view, the pane contains a listview, the ItemTemplate is a custom expander control, as I need to navigate only when the user clicks on the child item of the the expander control.

Comment: Would you mind adding some example code?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with the latest version of Template 10. There is a new Hamburger Button type called Literal, into which you can put anything.

Comment: Great! Thanks, I'll give it a try.
for now, I added it manually